# Why Instantiate JDialog changes the look of jpanel?

Tags: java

I´m making a game and created a dialog to choose a level.

in the jpanel i instantinate a jdialog:

```
private LevelDialog level_dialog = new LevelDialog("Choose Level", null);
```

I do it in the panel because it holds the game-controls, so i can add a key to show the dialog there.

But i noticed the following thing:

Normally the game-window fits exactly around the panel, but if the panel-class has the code line to instantiate the dialog, the game-window has narrow gaps at the right and bottom edges, out of the panel, that looks like to use for scrollbars.

I use

```
    g.setColor(new Color(127, 127, 0));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HIGHT);
```

to fill the whole panel with a background-color for the levels.

so i see theese gaps at theese two edges.

I tested, what caused them by commenting out all about the jdialog in the jpanel class ("//" in front of the lines).
if this is commented out, the jframe fits around the jpanel.
As i remuved the "//", where the jdialog is instantinated, the "scrollbar-gaps" appeared again.

How can i instantiate the jdialog without getting these gaps on the main-window of the game?

Comment: Could you provide more details about the layout of your components?

Comment: it is only the jpanel with the game-graphics in the jframe. And it should fill the whoole jframe. without instantinating the jdialog it looks exactly like i want it. so i wonder, why instantinating a jdialog changes the look of the main-frame...